# cannot read property name ; tagName null, while using svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

It's a duplicate question on SVG, but maybe my scenario is different, I am not able to understand any solution on the web for my problem which is, getting below error

ERROR in ./src/Utility/assets/customer-delight-logo.svg
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tagName')
at parse (C:\Customer delight\customerdelight\node_modules\svg-parser\dist\svg-parser.umd.js:279:15)......

my package.json contains

```
{
  "name": "customerdelight",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "webpack serve"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

this is my code

```
import Logo from '../../Utility/assets/customer-delight-logo.svg';

export default function Logocomp(){
    return(
    <div className="rad-logo-container">
        <img src={Logo} alt="" height="50" width="140"/>
     </div>
    )
}



Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: src="../../Utility/assets/customer-delight-logo.svg"

Comment: @HazratGafulov that is not working! i have tried it. rendering a broken pic!

Comment: then add div inside html and try add this svg to divs background.this will be work 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your webpack configuration to handle loading svg files. inside the `module.rules` array you should add the following:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|svg)$/,
  use: ['file-loader']
}
```